# Finding Matrix When Eigen Values & Eigen Vectors were known

Tags: python, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I have been trying to find my matrix from eigenvalues and eigenvectors.
I calculated eigen values and eigen vectors from a matrix first.
Then, I want to verify the values of eigenvalues and eigenvectors. But the didn't get the expected value.
[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Omaod.jpg)

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import eig
a=np.array([[1,2],[2,np.pi]])
w,v=eig(a)
c0=np.outer(v[0],v[0].T)
c1=np.outer(v[1],v[1].T)
a_=w[0]*c0+w[1]*c1
```

the result I got was:

```
array ([[ 1.     , -2.     ], 
        [-2.     ,  3.14159]])
```

but I was expecting same array as a. Can anyone tell me what's wrong here?

Comment: please add your code to the question as _plain text_ and not as image, thanks!!

Comment: ... one matrix is made of the eigenvectors, then compute its inverse. Do you know the change of base formula (or similarity relationship) is?

Comment: sorry, somehow I couldn't post my codes as normal text. that's why added an image. and I can't remember the base formula!

Comment: [change of basis formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis#Endomorphisms)

Answer (score 0):

Eigenvectors of `a` are not `v[0]` and `v[1]`. `v` is a transformation matrix. So columns of `v`, that is `v[:,0]` and `v[:,1]` are the eigenvectors.

You wrote the code as if `v[0]` and `v[1]` were eigenvectors, which they are not.

Also, I expect that you are aware that your code (once replaced `v[0]` and `v[1]` by `v[:,0]` and `v[:,1]`) only works because `v` is unitary and therefore `v⁻¹` is `vᵀ`.

Generic way to get back `a` would be `v@np.diag(w)@np.linalg.inv(v)`.
What you are doing is the equivalent of `v@np.diag(w)@v.T`. Which is ok, as long as `np.linalg.inv(v)` and `v.T` are the same thing. Which is the case when `v` is unitary.

Since your initial matrix `a` is symmetric, then we know that it exists a set of orthogonal eigenvectors, that form, once normalized, an unitary matrix. So, we know that a unitary matrix `v` is possible.

And because you have 2 different eigenvalues, in dimension 2, then, the vectors had to be orthogonal (each subspace is a line; so whatever eigenvector we choose, they are colinear the the eigenvectors of the orthogonal set we know exist). So in the case where `a` is symmetric, and you have as many eigenvalues as the dimension of `a`, `v` is orthogonal, and unitary, since `eig` garantees that each vector is normalized (norm 1)

But if `a` happened to have double eigenvalues, then, all we know is that `v` COULD be unitary, but `eig` doesn't guarantees that.

For example, a caricatural example, is `A=Identity`
Unique eigenvalue is 1. And eigenspace is the whole space. So any `v` made of two independent vectors is a valid `v`. Sure, there exist some unitary sets of eigenvectors (`[1,0], [0,1]` is the obvious one. And indeed `np.array([[1,0],[0,1]])@np.diag([1,1])@np.array([[1,0],[0,1]]).T`) is `A`. But there also exist others, non unitary, even after normalization. For example, `[1,0], [1/√2, 1/√2]` is another valid set of eigenvectors that could be returned by `eig` (both are eigenvectors. They form a valid basis of the eigenspace. And they are normalized).

Yet `np.array([[1, 1/np.sqrt(2)], [0, 1/np.sqrt(2)]])@np.diag([1,1])@np.array([[1, 1/np.sqrt(2)], [0, 1/np.sqrt(2)]]).T` is not `A` (`np.array([[1, 1/np.sqrt(2)], [0, 1/np.sqrt(2)]])@np.diag([1,1])@np.linalg.inv(np.array([[1, 1/np.sqrt(2)], [0, 1/np.sqrt(2)]]))` is).

So, long story short, in dim 2, even with symmetric matrices `a`, you have no guarantee that `v` is unitary. Maths tells that it could be. But `linalg.eig` doesn't guarantee that. And therefore, you don't know if `v@np.diag(w)@v.T` (which is what you compute, with longer code) is `a`.

On the other hand, `eigh`, which can be used only on hermitian matrices (so, symmetric ones in real world), guarantees that `v` is unitary.

So tl;dr

1. Your code assume that `v[0]` and `v[1]` are eigenvectors. They are not. `v[:,0]` and `v[:,1]` are.
2. Once that corrected, your code is the equivalent of computing `a_=v@np.diag(w)@v.T`
3. That is the same thing as `a` (which is equal to `v@np.diag(w)@np.linalg.inv(v)`) only if `v` is unitary. `eig` doesn't guarantee that it is the case (even if, `a` being symmetric, it is possible that it is). So, no guarantee that your code will find back `a` even after correction. Even tho, in your case (after correction) it happens to work.
4. `eigh`, which works only with symmetric (hermitians) matrices, as your `a` is, does guarantees that. So, Replace `eig` by `eigh` in your code. And then, you know for sure that (as long as `a` is symmetric), `a_` is `a`.